# Same SQL query written in two different ways giving me different results

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Queries are given below*

1.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME;
SET @StartDate = '2020-01-01 00:00:00.000'
SET @EndDate = '2020-01-31 23:59:59.999'
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,@StartDate,@EndDate)+1 AS No_Of_Days
```

2.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,'2020-01-01 00:00:00.000','2020-01-31 23:59:59.999')+1 AS No_Of_Days
```

Comment: `DATETIME` has only precision of around `1/300` of a second so `2020-01-31 23:59:59.999` is rounded up

Answer (score 5):

The problem comes from the precision of data types. In your first query, you're using `datetime` which is not accurate to the millisecond (it's rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds). So the first @EndDate is being rounded to `'2020-02-01'`, while the second one might be using datetime2 to keep the accuracy for all milliseconds and get the correct answer.

Here are some examples:

```
--Original query
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME;
SET @StartDate = '2020-01-01 00:00:00.000'
SET @EndDate = '2020-01-31 23:59:59.999'
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,@StartDate,@EndDate)+1 AS No_Of_Days, @StartDate,@EndDate
GO
--Using DATETIME2
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME2, @EndDate DATETIME2;
SET @StartDate = '2020-01-01 00:00:00.000'
SET @EndDate = '2020-01-31 23:59:59.999'
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,@StartDate,@EndDate)+1 AS No_Of_Days, @StartDate,@EndDate
GO
--Using DATETIME with correct milliseconds
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME;
SET @StartDate = '2020-01-01 00:00:00.000'
SET @EndDate = '2020-01-31 23:59:59.997'
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,@StartDate,@EndDate)+1 AS No_Of_Days, @StartDate,@EndDate
```

Comment: Thanks Lucis. It clarified everything.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above there is a difference between datetime and datetime2. The difference is explained in the link below

https://database.guide/datetime-vs-datetime2-in-sql-server-whats-the-difference/

One way to see the same results would be you cast the date-time in the query to datatype DATETIME

This should give you the same results

1.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME;
SET @StartDate = '2020-01-01 00:00:00.000'
SET @EndDate = '2020-01-31 23:59:59.999'
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,@StartDate,@EndDate)+1 AS No_Of_Days
```

2.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,cast('2020-01-01 00:00:00.000' as datetime),cast('2020-01-31 23:59:59.999' as datetime))+1 AS No_Of_Days
```

OR

Change the first query to datetime2

1.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME2, @EndDate DATETIME2;
SET @StartDate = '2020-01-01 00:00:00.000'
SET @EndDate = '2020-01-31 23:59:59.999'
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,@StartDate,@EndDate)+1 AS No_Of_Days
```

2.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,cast('2020-01-01 00:00:00.000' as datetime2),cast('2020-01-31 23:59:59.999' as datetime2))+1 AS No_Of_Days
```